# get t"TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'"

Tags: string, list, object, int, typeerror

i try to count all numbers in the list using a while loop.

```
lst = [65, 78, 21, 33]
sum1 = 0
wwea = 1

while wwea <= lst:
    sum1 = sum1 + wwea
    wwea += 1
print(sum1)
```

Comment: Please mention the language you are using

Answer (score 0):

Please mentions which lenguage you are using.

If python is the case, the operator `<=` cannot compare `int` type (which is the `wwea`) type and `list` type (of the `lst` variable).

If you try to **sum** all the elements in the list, then probably something like this will work, iterating the `wwea` up to the list's length:

```
lst = [65, 78, 21, 33]
sum1 = 0
wwea = 1

while wwea < len(lst):
    sum1 = sum1 + lst[wwea]
    wwea += 1
print(sum1)
```

If you are trying to **count** then:

```
lst = [65, 78, 21, 33]
sum1 = 0
wwea = 1

while wwea <= len(lst):
    sum1 = sum1 + 1
    wwea += 1
print(sum1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped - sorry for not mentioning PY3

Comment: With pleasure, please mark it as answered if it did helped :)